# How would you translate "too" and "to" as in "The science is *too* bookish and nerdy *to* understand, oh no!" to Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, syntax

So, how would you say "*The science is too bookish and nerdy to understand, oh no!*" in Latin? My attempt would be "*Scientia ita litteraria et incircumscripta est, ut non possit comprehendi, oh non!*".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*doctrina eruditior arcaniorque est quam ut intellegatur - eheu!*

'nerdy' is quite tough - *arcanus* doesn't quite get the nuance.

Comment: Nerd *is* tough. Traupman had *inconcinnus*. For bookworm, StackExchange has some suggestions: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/19455/booklover-in-latin

Comment: *pro dolor* might work for "oh no!". I'm not at all sure about "oh non" :)

Comment: I know a Latin teacher who likes to use *umbraticus* (someone who loves to stay in the shade, idly) for 'nerd' - at the very least a funny word choice