# How would you say "I am too stupid for this university." in Latin?

Tags: superlatives

In my [previous question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/20969/8533), I learned that, for example, "*I am too stupid to understand that.*" would be "*Stupidior sum quam ut id intellegam.*". But how would one say "*I am too stupid for this university.*" in Latin? My attempt would be "*Stupidior sum quam pro hac universitate.*", but I am not sure whether that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely comfortable with using *quam ut* and no verb - maybe someone else can confirm whether this is done or not. An easy way round would be to add a verb - i.e. "I'm too stupid to go to this university". By the way *stultus* is the normal word for 'stupid'. I would translate 'university' as *academia* (as in, Plato's Academy).

*stultior sum quam ut ad hanc academiam item*

PS Does anyone have a better suggestion for 'to go'? I've used the frequentative of *ire* but perhaps *assidere* or *apparare* + dat.?